# Can't load Region / State - Affiliate Register Page

Tags: field, opencart, region, affiliate, zone

I am building a website with Opencart 1.5.3.1, but I get the problem with Affiliate Register Page.

http://www.officexinh.com/index.php?route=affiliate/register

(Language: Vietnamese - Region / State is "Quận / Huyện:")

- When a user creates a new account, the "Affiliate" register page loads very slowly
  , and the Region / State box does not show the value.
- However, my "Account" register page does not has this bug!!!

**1. catalog/controller/affiliate/register.php**

```
    <?php 
class ControllerAffiliateRegister extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        if ($this->affiliate->isLogged()) {
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('affiliate/account', '', 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->language->load('affiliate/register');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('affiliate/affiliate');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $this->model_affiliate_affiliate->addAffiliate($this->request->post);

            $this->affiliate->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password']);

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('affiliate/success'));
        } 

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),         
            'separator' => false
        ); 

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_account'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('affiliate/account', '', 'SSL'),        
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_register'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('affiliate/register', '', 'SSL'),       
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
        $this->data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
        $this->data['text_account_already'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_account_already'), $this->url->link('affiliate/login', '', 'SSL'));
        $this->data['text_signup'] = $this->language->get('text_signup');
        $this->data['text_your_details'] = $this->language->get('text_your_details');
        $this->data['text_your_address'] = $this->language->get('text_your_address');
        $this->data['text_payment'] = $this->language->get('text_payment');
        $this->data['text_your_password'] = $this->language->get('text_your_password');
        $this->data['text_cheque'] = $this->language->get('text_cheque');
        $this->data['text_paypal'] = $this->language->get('text_paypal');
        $this->data['text_bank'] = $this->language->get('text_bank');

        $this->data['entry_lastname'] = $this->language->get('entry_lastname');
        $this->data['entry_firstname'] = $this->language->get('entry_firstname');
        $this->data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $this->data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
        $this->data['entry_fax'] = $this->language->get('entry_fax');
        $this->data['entry_company'] = $this->language->get('entry_company');
        $this->data['entry_website'] = $this->language->get('entry_website');
        $this->data['entry_address_1'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_1');
        $this->data['entry_address_2'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_2');
        $this->data['entry_postcode'] = $this->language->get('entry_postcode');
        $this->data['entry_city'] = $this->language->get('entry_city');
        $this->data['entry_country'] = $this->language->get('entry_country');
        $this->data['entry_zone'] = $this->language->get('entry_zone');
        $this->data['entry_tax'] = $this->language->get('entry_tax');
        $this->data['entry_payment'] = $this->language->get('entry_payment');
        $this->data['entry_cheque'] = $this->language->get('entry_cheque');
        $this->data['entry_paypal'] = $this->language->get('entry_paypal');
        $this->data['entry_bank_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_bank_name');
        $this->data['entry_bank_branch_number'] = $this->language->get('entry_bank_branch_number');
        $this->data['entry_bank_swift_code'] = $this->language->get('entry_bank_swift_code');
        $this->data['entry_bank_account_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_bank_account_name');
        $this->data['entry_bank_account_number'] = $this->language->get('entry_bank_account_number');
        $this->data['entry_password'] = $this->language->get('entry_password');
        $this->data['entry_confirm'] = $this->language->get('entry_confirm');

        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['lastname'])) {
            $this->data['error_lastname'] = $this->error['lastname'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_lastname'] = '';
        }   

        if (isset($this->error['firstname'])) {
            $this->data['error_firstname'] = $this->error['firstname'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_firstname'] = '';
        }       

        if (isset($this->error['email'])) {
            $this->data['error_email'] = $this->error['email'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['telephone'])) {
            $this->data['error_telephone'] = $this->error['telephone'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_telephone'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['password'])) {
            $this->data['error_password'] = $this->error['password'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_password'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['confirm'])) {
            $this->data['error_confirm'] = $this->error['confirm'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_confirm'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['address_1'])) {
            $this->data['error_address_1'] = $this->error['address_1'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_address_1'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['city'])) {
            $this->data['error_city'] = $this->error['city'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_city'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['postcode'])) {
            $this->data['error_postcode'] = $this->error['postcode'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_postcode'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['country'])) {
            $this->data['error_country'] = $this->error['country'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_country'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['zone'])) {
            $this->data['error_zone'] = $this->error['zone'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_zone'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('affiliate/register', '', 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->post['lastname'])) {
            $this->data['lastname'] = $this->request->post['lastname'];
        } else {
            $this->data['lastname'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
            $this->data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
        } else {
            $this->data['firstname'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $this->data['email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
            $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone'];
        } else {
            $this->data['telephone'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['fax'])) {
            $this->data['fax'] = $this->request->post['fax'];
        } else {
            $this->data['fax'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['company'])) {
            $this->data['company'] = $this->request->post['company'];
        } else {
            $this->data['company'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['website'])) {
            $this->data['website'] = $this->request->post['website'];
        } else {
            $this->data['website'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['address_1'])) {
            $this->data['address_1'] = $this->request->post['address_1'];
        } else {
            $this->data['address_1'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['address_2'])) {
            $this->data['address_2'] = $this->request->post['address_2'];
        } else {
            $this->data['address_2'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['postcode'])) {
            $this->data['postcode'] = $this->request->post['postcode'];
        } else {
            $this->data['postcode'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['city'])) {
            $this->data['city'] = $this->request->post['city'];
        } else {
            $this->data['city'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
            $this->data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];
        } else {    
            $this->data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
            $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->request->post['zone_id'];   
        } else {
            $this->data['zone_id'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');

        $this->data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

        if (isset($this->request->post['tax'])) {
            $this->data['tax'] = $this->request->post['tax'];
        } else {
            $this->data['tax'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['payment'])) {
            $this->data['payment'] = $this->request->post['payment'];
        } else {
            $this->data['payment'] = 'cheque';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['cheque'])) {
            $this->data['cheque'] = $this->request->post['cheque'];
        } else {
            $this->data['cheque'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['paypal'])) {
            $this->data['paypal'] = $this->request->post['paypal'];
        } else {
            $this->data['paypal'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['bank_name'])) {
            $this->data['bank_name'] = $this->request->post['bank_name'];
        } else {
            $this->data['bank_name'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['bank_branch_number'])) {
            $this->data['bank_branch_number'] = $this->request->post['bank_branch_number'];
        } else {
            $this->data['bank_branch_number'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['bank_swift_code'])) {
            $this->data['bank_swift_code'] = $this->request->post['bank_swift_code'];
        } else {
            $this->data['bank_swift_code'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['bank_account_name'])) {
            $this->data['bank_account_name'] = $this->request->post['bank_account_name'];
        } else {
            $this->data['bank_account_name'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['bank_account_number'])) {
            $this->data['bank_account_number'] = $this->request->post['bank_account_number'];
        } else {
            $this->data['bank_account_number'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
            $this->data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
        } else {
            $this->data['password'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['confirm'])) {
            $this->data['confirm'] = $this->request->post['confirm'];
        } else {
            $this->data['confirm'] = '';
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_affiliate_id')) {
            $this->load->model('catalog/information');

            $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_affiliate_id'));

            if ($information_info) {
                $this->data['text_agree'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_agree'), $this->url->link('information/information/info', 'information_id=' . $this->config->get('config_affiliate_id'), 'SSL'), $information_info['title'], $information_info['title']);
            } else {
                $this->data['text_agree'] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['text_agree'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
            $this->data['agree'] = $this->request->post['agree'];
        } else {
            $this->data['agree'] = false;
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/affiliate/register.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/affiliate/register.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/affiliate/register.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header' 
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());    
    }

    private function validate() {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['lastname']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['lastname']) > 32)) {
            $this->error['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) > 32)) {
            $this->error['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
        }

        if ($this->model_affiliate_affiliate->getTotalAffiliatesByEmail($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
            $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['address_1']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['address_1']) > 128)) {
            $this->error['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['city']) < 2) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['city']) > 128)) {
            $this->error['city'] = $this->language->get('error_city');
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');

        $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->post['country_id']);

        if ($country_info && $country_info['postcode_required'] && (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['postcode']) < 2) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['postcode']) > 10)) {
            $this->error['postcode'] = $this->language->get('error_postcode');
        }

        if ($this->request->post['country_id'] == '') {
            $this->error['country'] = $this->language->get('error_country');
        }

        if ($this->request->post['zone_id'] == '') {
            $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) > 20)) {
            $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
        }

        if ($this->request->post['confirm'] != $this->request->post['password']) {
            $this->error['confirm'] = $this->language->get('error_confirm');
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_affiliate_id')) {
            $this->load->model('catalog/information');

            $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_affiliate_id'));

            if ($information_info && !isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
                $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_agree'), $information_info['title']);
            }
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function country() {
        $json = array();

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');

        $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->get['country_id']);

        if ($country_info) {
            $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

            $json = array(
                'country_id'        => $country_info['country_id'],
                'name'              => $country_info['name'],
                'iso_code_2'        => $country_info['iso_code_2'],
                'iso_code_3'        => $country_info['iso_code_3'],
                'address_format'    => $country_info['address_format'],
                'postcode_required' => $country_info['postcode_required'],
                'zone'              => $this->model_localisation_zone->getZonesByCountryId($this->request->get['country_id']),
                'status'            => $country_info['status']      
            );
        }

        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }   
}
?>
```

**2. catalog/controller/affiliate/register.tpl**

```
   I cut the first part of the full code because Stackoverflow allows the posted content not over 300000 characters. However, the fist part is default in Opencart installation...


        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_address; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="50" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_website; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="50" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="50" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_city; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="50" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_city) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_city; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span id="postcode-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="50" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_postcode) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_postcode; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
              <td><select name="country_id" onchange="$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=' + this.value + '&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');">
                  <option value="false"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                  <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
              <td><select name="zone_id">
                </select>
                <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_payment; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_tax; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="tax" value="<?php echo $tax; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_payment; ?></td>
                <td><?php if ($payment == 'cheque') { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cheque" id="cheque" checked="checked" />
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="cheque" id="cheque" />
                  <?php } ?>
                  <label for="cheque"><?php echo $text_cheque; ?></label>
                  <?php if ($payment == 'paypal') { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal" id="paypal" checked="checked" />
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal" id="paypal" />
                  <?php } ?>
                  <label for="paypal"><?php echo $text_paypal; ?></label>
                  <?php if ($payment == 'bank') { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="bank" id="bank" checked="checked" />
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="bank" id="bank" />
                  <?php } ?>
                  <label for="bank"><?php echo $text_bank; ?></label></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody id="payment-cheque" class="payment">
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_cheque; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="cheque" value="<?php echo $cheque; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="payment" id="payment-paypal">
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_paypal; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="paypal" value="<?php echo $paypal; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody id="payment-bank" class="payment">
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_bank_name; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="bank_name" value="<?php echo $bank_name; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_bank_branch_number; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="bank_branch_number" value="<?php echo $bank_branch_number; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_bank_swift_code; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="bank_swift_code" value="<?php echo $bank_swift_code; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_bank_account_name; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="bank_account_name" value="<?php echo $bank_account_name; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $entry_bank_account_number; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="bank_account_number" value="<?php echo $bank_account_number; ?>" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_password; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" size="50" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" size="50" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirm; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>
            <?php if ($agree) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </form>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=affiliate/register/country&country_id=' + this.value,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.wait').remove();
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                    $('#postcode-required').show();
                } else {
                    $('#postcode-required').hide();
                }

                html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

                if (json['zone'] != '') {
                    for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                        if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $zone_id; ?>') {
                            html += ' selected="selected"';
                        }

                        html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
                }

                $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
    //--></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('input[name=\'payment\']').bind('change', function() {
        $('.payment').hide();

        $('#payment-' + this.value).show();
    });

    $('input[name=\'payment\']:checked').trigger('change');
    //--></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    });
    //--></script> 
    <?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the country (Khu vực) is changed, not only the `affiliate/register/country` is triggered but also `account/register/zone` is registered and also for each such request the whole HTML page with loading of other JS and CSS resources is loaded via AJAX requests, which is really strange. Normally the JS and CSS resources should be cached within the browser so loading them per each request wouldn't be a problem, but as You could see within Your Firebug Console Tab, each JS resource has a timestampt hash within the URL, therefore it is really loaded each time.

Since You cannot post the whole template and I do not see nothing wrong in the controller file posted nor JS within the template I do not see any problem there.

Maybe You binded some JS function also in global JS file for `<select name="country">` that's being called also now.